# Firebase authentication facebook provider usage with signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential()

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up facebook sign-in to my react-native app using firebase. I am successfully authenticating with facebook using the integrated facebook support with expo and am getting a facebook-token. Unfortunately however, I'm having issues using this token to sign-in with firebase getting a "Invalid IdP response/credential" error.

I have used the exact same flow (but using Google Provider and token) for google login and been successful. I have also been able to use the facebook token to get data from facebook's rest API showing validity of token.

```
    //This function gives the error

    doSignInWithFacebookCredential = (facebookToken) => {
        const credential = this.facebookProvider.credential(facebookToken);
        this.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
        .then(authUser => {
            alert("It worked!")
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            alert(error)
        });
    }



    //Code used to verify facebook token

    const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${facebookToken}`);
    console.log(await response.json())



    //This function works perfectly (The google sign-in with same flow)

    doSignInWithGoogleCredential = (googleToken) => {
        const credential = this.googleProvider.credential(googleToken);
        console.log(credential)
        this.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
        .then(authUser => {
            alert("It worked!")
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            alert(error)
        });
    }
```

After receiving the valid facebook token an error occurs resulting in an alert from the catch that says

`Error: Invalid IdP response/credential: http://localhost?id_token=$facebookToken&providerId=facebook.com`

[image]

TLDR; Despite having a valid facebook token it seems `facebookProvider.credential(facebookToken)` is not giving a valid token to the `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential()` function causing a 'Invalid IdP response/credential' error.

If anyone has worked with these methods before or has any suggestions they are all greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Thrown if the credential is malformed or has expired, and for that reason it returns invalid idp response credentials.

Since This method is deprecated, i suggest to use **firebase.auth.Auth.signInWithCredential** instead. And, maybe in this way, you will get more details if there is a problem with credential or not

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response and info. I have tried signInWithCredential() but have the same issue with it, and strangely enough it seems the docs and library disagree on what of the methods is deprecated as when I use signInWithCredential() I get console warnings that this is deprecated. Are you sure signInWithCredential() is the one not deprecated as I will move to that and ignore the console errors? Also do you know if the oauth token for the credential must be a JWT as the token I get from facebook isn't but the token via my google implementation is.

Comment: Hmm, seems very weird that the library disagree on what of the methods is deprecated.  I am pretty sure that: signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential() is the deprecated one, since also is documented on the Firebase Documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinandretrievedatawithcredential 
The oauth token for the credentials must be a JWT, what type of token do you get from facebook?

Comment: I know, I am so confused docs say use signInWithCredential, and then I get this in the console `firebase.auth.Auth.prototype.signInWithCredential is deprecated. Please use firebase.auth.Auth.prototype.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential instead.`

Comment: It not very clear what kind of token is returned however according to expo docs this can be used as I am trying - https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase/#user-authentication. I wonder if there has been update that has recently changed the token type returned hence this is no longer working?

Comment: I don't think that there has been an update recently, i am using also the firebase for an app that i have developed with expo react native, but i have not got any reports for any problems with the token, recently

Comment: Are you using the same system of getting a facebook token and then using that to log in with credential into firebase?

Comment: Yeap, and if you check the documentation on expo for this part you will also see this: **the token that is received from a successful login can be passed to the Firebase SDK to provide us with a Firebase credential via firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential. We can then sign-in with this credential via firebase.auth().signInWithCredential**

Comment: Is  your source code public on GitHub that I could read through and see if I have made a typo or something?

Comment: No it is a private repository. Application for customer. But i will try to update you with my lines of code when i find it possible

Comment: Got the issue solved in the strangest way. Redid the import of firebase and it worked. Confuses me so much as anything missing should have caused a crash but I guess I shouldn't question a positive outcome.

Comment: Perfect. Great 